# Addition problems in Python 3.5

Tags: javascript, python, addition

I am having trouble figuring out how to use addition in Python 3.5 (other than:

```
number++
number++
number++
number++
number++
```

and so on... just to add 5 to number.

I am also having this problem in JavaScript, and I believe it is language wide.

I am more fluent in javascript so I will use js for the example:

```
var num1 = 5;
var num2 = 5;
var num3 = num1 + num2;
/*For those not inclined to js, alert() is like print(), but it 
shows up in a dialog box/popup  */

alert(num3)
```

That would alert "55", not 10.
Please explain.

Comment: That first block isn't Python, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: And the second block produces `10` for me.

Comment: yea sorry, just quickly ran it in idle, sytax err

Comment: In Javascript think you got `'55'` because you did `'5' + '5'` not `5 + 5`

Comment: the js is num1 + num2

Comment: Yeah, that produces `10`. So the first block is totally invalid and the second block isn't reproducible.

Comment: ok i swear it has never had your results for me, now all of a sudden it is, this is really odd

Comment: I put details about my comment in my answer, because too long a trace, we can delete it all when done :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please explain.

Well, the first block, with `number++`, isn't valid Python. You have to use a more verbose construct like one of the following:

```
number = number + 1
```

or

```
number += 1
```

Now that the increment value is explicitly stated, I'm sure you can see how we change that to 5:

```
number = number + 5
```

or

```
number += 5
```

And the block of JS that you posted does not produce the stated result. I get the following:

```js
> var x = 5
> undefined
> var y = 5
> undefined
> x+y
> 10
> alert(x+y)
> undefined // it produced 10
```

Answer (score 3):

The `++` operator isn't in Python, as it mixes *expressions* and *statements* in a single operation. So the closest you can do is `n += 1`

To add five to the number do

```
n = 0
n += 5
```

Too large to put in comments about the JS, I think you just weren't paying attention, because for char/string JS will concatenate and produce the result string `'55'` instead of the number `55`. You will get an actual math addition if it's of a number type, see below:

```
// Strings
num1 = '5'
"5"
num2 = '5'
"5"
num1 + num2
"55"

// Numbers
num1 = 5
5
num2 = 5
5
num1 + num2 
10
```